# Automatically recalculate results

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming

Basically, I want to be able to write some code like the following:

```
main = do
  x <- newVal (2 :: Int)
  y <- newVal (3 :: Int)
  z <- newFunc (x, y) (\(a,b) -> a * b) 
  r1 <- readVal z
  print r1 -- prints 6 (2 * 3)
  setVal x 5
  r2 <- readVal z
  print r2 -- prints 15 (5 * 3)
```

Could someone provide some sample code from scratch or from a library that would allow me to achieve something like the above?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? and what is `newVal`, `newFunc`, `setVal` etc ?

Comment: @Sibi My guess from my reactive programming experience, `newVal` creates a value that can/will change (think a cell of a spread sheet) and `newFunc` creates a "formula" and stores the result in `z` so that the result auto-updates when you `setVal` anything

Comment: @sibi jozefg is correct. You define them, they're for illustrative purposes only. The expected output should make it clear what I'm trying to achieve, I don't mind if you suggest an approach which is a little different

Comment: @Clinton: You're going to have to accept some alterations for your syntax, because note that the value that comes out of `x <- newVal (2 :: Int)` is the value that goes into `setVal x 5`, and this isn't going to give you semantics that you want, in general.  Something similar looking should be possible in ST though.

Comment: @TomEllis No, the x that comes out of newVal would be an IOref or STref, not an actual value. The syntax does make sense.

Comment: @chunksOf50: In that case you wouldn't be able to write `newFunc` as given, without some sort of "lifting".  (See my answer below).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying @ellis. I'm pretty much using the IORef syntax.

Comment: @Clinton: Check my answer below!  Note that it is not possible to write `newFunc` with the syntax you've given it, but you can write `liftIORef2` for 2-tuples, `liftIORef3` for 3-tuples, etc..

Comment: @Clinton: If you knew it was the `IORef` syntax, why didn't you just write it yourself using `IORef`?!

Comment: @TomEllis Yes; newFunc could only create a two-argument function, but it's also surely possible to use Applicative to generalise to arbitrary numbers of arguments (because secretly there's only ever one argument). The satement could become `z <- newFunc $ (*) <$> x <*> y`.

Comment: @TomEllis You would need to put more in the IOref than just a value, you'd need to store an IO() of what else to update when you setValue if you do it this way, though; a heavy price to pay for removing the word let.

Comment: @chunksOf50: Sure, you can do that, that's a nice idea.  Perhaps I took Clinton too literally.  I just meant that you can't have the exact syntax Clinton proposed for `newVal` *and* `newFunc` *and* `readVal`.

Comment: ....if newFunc is polymorphic. Indeed.

Answer (score 5):

This is almost exactly the functionality of `STRef` and `IORef`, except as I alluded to in my comment above, you can't get a completely polymorphic `newFunc`.  You have to do something analagous to `liftA2`.

```
import Data.IORef

main = do
  x <- newVal (2 :: Int)
  y <- newVal (3 :: Int)
  let z = liftIORef2 (x, y) (\(a,b) -> a * b) 
  r1 <- readVal z
  print r1 -- prints 6 (2 * 3)
  setVal x 5
  r2 <- readVal z
  print r2 -- prints 15 (5 * 3)

liftIORef2 (a, b) f = do
  a' <- readIORef a
  b' <- readIORef b
  return (f (a', b'))

newVal = newIORef

setVal = writeIORef

readVal = id

*Main> main
6
15
```

Answer (score 2):

One can see your program as an example of *incremental computing*, and here is one solution that uses the library [Adaptive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Adaptive), which can be used to express such incremental computing problems.

```
import Control.Monad.Adaptive (newMod, readMod, inM, change, propagate, run)

main :: IO ()
main = run $ do
  x <- newMod $ return 2
  y <- newMod $ return 3
  z <- newMod $ do
    a <- readMod x
    b <- readMod y
    return (a * b)
  newMod $ do -- For observing 'z'
    r <- readMod z
    inM $ print r
  -- prints 6 (2 * 3)
  change x 5
  propagate  -- prints 15 (5 * 3)
```

The Adaptive library is a Haskell implementation by me that closely follows the nice POPL 2002 paper [Adaptive Functional Programming](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~blelloch/papers/popl02.pdf) by Acar, Blelloch and Harper.

Instead of `newVal`, one uses `newMod`, which creates a "modifiable", a computation that keeps track of which other modifiables it depends on when it reads them by `readMod`.  Later, one can change modifiables by `change` followed by `propagate`, and all the modifiables that depend on the changed ones automatically gets recomputed in the right order.  One can observe what is going on by adding side effects to the computations that define modifiables, and that is how we can see what happens to `z`.

You can read more about the Haskell implementation in the paper [Monads for Incremental Computing](http://www.carlssonia.org/ogi/papers/icfp-2002.pdf) that I wrote for ICFP 2002.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will provide you with an FRP answer, for now I'll show you how to make a reactive system with STM.

First we'll need to explicitly declare your transactional variables and setup the producer and the consumer.  The "producer" in this example is your `newFunc` which reads `x` and `y` to produce a new `z`.  The "consumer" reads `z` and prints it if it changed.

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

f = do
  x <- newTVarIO 2
  y <- newTVarIO 3
  z <- newTVarIO 0
  forkIO $ newFunc 2 3 (x,y) z
  loop z 0
```

So that's pretty straight forward.  Since it's simple, let's look at the thread monitoring and printing `z`.  The notion is we remember what the last value was and only print `z` if the value has changed.  The trick is in `retry`, which will only wake up our thread if the `TVar` is written by another transaction.

```
loop z zV = do
             print zV
             v <- atomically $ do
                     new_zV <- readTVar z
                     when (zV == new_zV) retry
                     return zV
             loop z v
```

That simple pattern of read-compare-{retry or compute} is powerful and exactly what we need for `newFunc`.  We'll read all the values and `retry` conditional on if the inputs haven't changes and the result is correct (adjust this to fit your needs).

```
newFunc :: Int -> Int -> (TVar Int , TVar Int) -> TVar Int -> IO ()
newFunc xV yV (x, y) z = atomically $ do
  newX  <- readTVar x
  newY  <- readTVar y
  currZ <- readTVar z
  let result = newX * newY
  when (newX == xV && newY == yV && currZ == result) retry
  writeTVar z result
```